# running script on GA spreadsheet without changing previous spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some data and formulae on a Google Spreadsheet.
I want to run  a  new script on it which retrieves data from Google Analytics and displays it in some specific cells(mentioned in script) on the spreadsheet.
But the problem is, when I run the script, all the previous data and formulae on the spreadsheet is lost.
Is there any way by which I can keep the previous data , and at the same time run the script.??

Comment: Could you please post the script? The api presumably does not remove all data prior to inserting new records.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`Sheet.clear()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear%28%29) unless you want to clear all previous content.